# Using moment.js to indicate when mongoDB/mongoose was last updated?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I have a table populated with data from my mongoDB and I want to use moment.js to indicate the last date/time any entry in the table was edited and updated.

My issue is that moment.js seems to be showing the date/time in real time, rather than only when a database entry was edited.

How do I get it to show the correct date and time?

Mongoose Schema, where I use timestamps for the `updatedAt` feature:

```js
var environmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ePIMS: String,
    codeVersion: String,
    region: String
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });
```

HTML where I'm trying to use moment.js

````html
<table>
   <%= moment(environments.updatedAt) %> <!-- using it here causes the date/time to update in real time -->

   <% environments.forEach(function(environment){ %>
    <!-- if I use the moment.js code here, it shows it 3 times for all three of the ```td```'s below -->
     <tr>

         <td><%= environment.ePIMS %></td>
         <td><%= environment.codeVersion %></td>
         <td><%= environment.region %></td>

     </tr>
   <% }); %> 
 </table>
````

By the way, it works when I put the moment.js code in my forEach loop where my mongo collection (`environments`) is being called, but then it shows a date and time for every single entry of my database, and updates those dates/times individually. Is there a way to do it this way but only have one date/time for all entries?

Answer (score 0):

- Environments is an array of environment objects and you are trying to get updatedAt of that.
- You need to get one environment object and get UpdatedAt of that single object.
- So you can put [index] mostly [0] `environments[0].updatedAt` to get the updatedAt of the first environment.
- To get the lastest one go with `sort({"updatedAt": -1})` and then `environments[0].updatedAt`

Comment: Is there a way to have 1 date/time shown for all the environments? Instead of an individual date/time for each environment every time it's updated? This method works for just displaying the date/time when the first environment is updated, but I'm trying to have 1 date/time for all environments..

Comment: One solution I can think of right now is use `sort({"updatedAt": -1})` with your query so the first environment will have latest datetime.